Placing a second plot on the x-axis of another plot in ggplot2
I'm trying to create a stacked Barplot where one of the Bars is way shorter than the other ones. To make the small bar more understandable I tried to add in a "zoomed In" Plot of the smaller bar, but I can't get it to align with my bar, because my Y-Axis is categorial and I don't know how I can place the second plot in the space between Axis and Plot. The second Plot would have to sit/start "on the X-Axis" to perfectly align both bars

This is an example code for my problem.
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
Depth <- c("10-20m","10-20m","10-20m","20-40m","20-40m","20-40m","30-60m","30-60m","30-60m")
Animal <- c("Fish", "Turtle", "Shark", "Fish", "Turtle", "Shark", "Fish", "Turtle", "Shark")
Abundance <- c(10,20, 15, 500, 500, 500, 1000, 1000, 1000)
BigPlotdata <- data.frame(Depth, Animal, Abundance)






Bigplot <- ggplot(BigPlotdata, aes(fill = Animal, x = Abundance, y = Depth))+
  geom_bar(position = "stack" , stat = "identity")


Zoomed <- filter(BigPlotdata, Depth == "10-20m")
ZoomIn <- ggplot(Zoomed, aes(fill = Animal, x = Abundance, y = Depth)) +
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat= "identity")+
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank())

PlotwithZoom <- Bigplot + annotation_custom(ggplotGrob(ZoomIn), xmin = 500, xmax = 3000, ymin = "10-20m" , ymax = "20-40m")

I added the second Plot via annotations_custom(). Is there a way to put something into the ymin argument so the second plot will sit on my x-Axis and align with the smallest bar from the bigger Plot?

You could try something like       PlotwithZoom <- Bigplot + annotation_custom(ggplotGrob(ZoomIn), xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = -Inf , ymax = "10-20m")
but it's not as ideal as you have stacked bar so the zoom effect is not as stretched when using Inf as the constraint

Showing percentages within each group is an alternative option. You could add group sample sizes on the end of bars as well.

Well, even if your deal with a discrete positional scale you can still use numbers, i.e. as suggested by @summer7 you can use ymin=-Inf to place the zoomed plot on the x-axis and to align the plot with the bar use xmax = 1 + .45 where 1 is the numeric position of first category and .45 is half of the bar width:
library(ggplot2)

Bigplot +
  annotation_custom(ggplotGrob(ZoomIn),
    xmin = 500, xmax = 3000,
    ymin = -Inf, ymax = 1 + .45
  )


Personally I would go for a true inset plot and, to help the reader, add some kind of hint to make clear that the small figure is a zoomed version of the small bar. Such an alternative may look like so, where I also added an invisible top axis to align the zoomed and unzoomed bars as well as the grid lines.
x <- c(550, 550, 100, 100)
y <- c(1 + .4, 1 - .4, 1 - .45, 1 + .45)
Bigplot +
  annotation_custom(
    ggplotGrob(
      ZoomIn +
        scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis()) +
        theme(
          axis.text.x.top = element_text(color = NA),
          axis.ticks.x.top = element_line(color = NA)
        )
    ),
    xmin = 600, xmax = 3000,
    ymin = 1 - .4, ymax = 1 + .4
  ) +
  annotate(
    geom = "polygon",
    x = x, y = y,
    fill = "grey75",
    alpha = .6
  ) +
  annotate(
    geom = "polygon",
    x = x, y = y,
    group = c(1, 2, 2, 1),
    color = "grey55"
  )



Here's an alternative approach using ggforce::facet_zoom.
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

Depth <- c("10-20m","10-20m","10-20m","20-40m","20-40m","20-40m","30-60m","30-60m","30-60m")
Animal <- c("Fish", "Turtle", "Shark", "Fish", "Turtle", "Shark", "Fish", "Turtle", "Shark")
Abundance <- c(10,20, 15, 500, 500, 500, 1000, 1000, 1000)
BigPlotdata <- data.frame(Depth, Animal, Abundance)

ggplot(BigPlotdata, aes(fill = Animal, x = Abundance, y = Depth))+
  geom_bar(position = "stack" , stat = "identity") +
  ggforce::facet_zoom(x = Depth == "10-20m",
                      zoom.data = Depth == "10-20m",
                      zoom.size = 0.5) +
  theme_bw()


Created on 2024-05-15 with reprex v2.1.0

Haha. Using facet_zoom was my first thought, too. And I borrowed the idea with the polygons from it. :D

Facet_zoom sounds is also new to me and sounds useful aswell! The other solution is just more what I was looking for with my problem
